# subrange of Z3 integers

Tags: z3, modulo

it seems, there is no good support for integer-subranges in Z3. One would have to restrict all 'constants' and results with

```
 `(assert (and (<= 0 x) (<= x nMax )))`.
```

Wouldn't it be useful to have something like a 'modular integer' type, with values between 0 and n? I could go for bitvectors, but not all of my n are powers of two.

How can i express something like x must be one of [ 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13] ? Some kind of set-membership? list-operation ? Only bitvectors ??

Comment: See also Levent Erkok's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/49682830/491216. Bottom line: there isn't a good way of doing this using SMT-LIB.

Comment: i found out, that the constraint can be formulated as

Comment: i found out, that the constraint can also be formulated as
   `(assert (<=  0  x  nMax ) )`
But still performance is rediciously low. I would like to write a small paper about the problem and discuss it with some expert(s). Maybe my constraints are rediciously silly or there _is_ a problem in Z3. Basically i want to classify 36 objects into 3 bins - and a night isnt enough to get a result...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any solver that supports modular arithmetic natively.
You can use bit-vectors + <= constraints.

Comment: then they should learn it. After all, a constraint solver tries to learn more and more limitaions from the given constraints to cut the search space and find a combination of values for the result. Modular integer arithmetic would limit the search space from the very beginning.